# How to install particular font in nokia?

Tags: symbian

How to install font in nokia handset actually handsets with symbian installed on it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Open Font System](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_install_a_font_file)

OR

- [How To Change Fonts On Your Symbian Phone](http://www.symbian-guru.com/welcome/2009/08/how-to-change-fonts-on-your-symbian-phone.html)